# More efficient method for counting open cases as of creation time of each case

Tags: r, performance, data.table, dplyr, vectorization

I am trying find a more efficient way to count the number of cases that are open as of the creation time of each case.  A case is "open" between its creation date/time stamp and its censor date/time stamp.  You can copy-paste the code below to view a simple functional example:

```
# Create a bunch of date/time stamps for our example
two_thousand                <- as.POSIXct("2000-01-01 00:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC", origin="1970-01-01");
two_thousand_one            <- as.POSIXct("2001-01-01 00:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC", origin="1970-01-01");
two_thousand_two            <- as.POSIXct("2002-01-01 00:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC", origin="1970-01-01");
two_thousand_three          <- as.POSIXct("2003-01-01 00:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC", origin="1970-01-01");
two_thousand_four           <- as.POSIXct("2004-01-01 00:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC", origin="1970-01-01");
two_thousand_five           <- as.POSIXct("2005-01-01 00:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC", origin="1970-01-01");
two_thousand_six            <- as.POSIXct("2006-01-01 00:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC", origin="1970-01-01");
two_thousand_seven          <- as.POSIXct("2007-01-01 00:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC", origin="1970-01-01");
two_thousand_eight          <- as.POSIXct("2008-01-01 00:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC", origin="1970-01-01");
two_thousand_nine           <- as.POSIXct("2009-01-01 00:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC", origin="1970-01-01");
two_thousand_ten            <- as.POSIXct("2010-01-01 00:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC", origin="1970-01-01");
two_thousand_eleven         <- as.POSIXct("2011-01-01 00:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC", origin="1970-01-01");

mid_two_thousand            <- as.POSIXct("2000-06-01 00:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC", origin="1970-01-01");
mid_two_thousand_one        <- as.POSIXct("2001-06-01 00:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC", origin="1970-01-01");
mid_two_thousand_mid_two    <- as.POSIXct("2002-06-01 00:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC", origin="1970-01-01");
mid_two_thousand_three      <- as.POSIXct("2003-06-01 00:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC", origin="1970-01-01");
mid_two_thousand_four       <- as.POSIXct("2004-06-01 00:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC", origin="1970-01-01");
mid_two_thousand_five       <- as.POSIXct("2005-06-01 00:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC", origin="1970-01-01");
mid_two_thousand_six        <- as.POSIXct("2006-06-01 00:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC", origin="1970-01-01");
mid_two_thousand_seven      <- as.POSIXct("2007-06-01 00:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC", origin="1970-01-01");
mid_two_thousand_eight      <- as.POSIXct("2008-06-01 00:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC", origin="1970-01-01");
mid_two_thousand_nine       <- as.POSIXct("2009-06-01 00:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC", origin="1970-01-01");
mid_two_thousand_ten        <- as.POSIXct("2010-06-01 00:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC", origin="1970-01-01");
mid_two_thousand_eleven     <- as.POSIXct("2011-06-01 00:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC", origin="1970-01-01");

# Create a table that has pairs of created & censored date/time stamps for cases, indicating the range during which each case is "open"
comparison_table    <- data.table(id        = 1:10,
                                  created   = c(two_thousand, two_thousand_two, two_thousand_four, two_thousand_six, two_thousand_eight, two_thousand_ten, two_thousand, two_thousand_six, two_thousand_three, two_thousand_one),
                                  censored  = c(two_thousand_one, two_thousand_three, two_thousand_five, two_thousand_seven, two_thousand_nine, two_thousand_eleven, two_thousand_five, two_thousand_ten, two_thousand_eight, two_thousand_four));

# Create a table that has the creation date/time stamps at which we want to count all the open cases
check_table         <- data.table(id        = 1:12,
                                  creation  = c(mid_two_thousand, mid_two_thousand_one, mid_two_thousand_mid_two, mid_two_thousand_three, mid_two_thousand_four, mid_two_thousand_five, mid_two_thousand_six, mid_two_thousand_seven, mid_two_thousand_eight, mid_two_thousand_nine, mid_two_thousand_ten, mid_two_thousand_eleven)); 

# I use the DPLYR library as the group_by() + summarize() functions make this operation simple
library(dplyr);

# Group by id to set parameter for summarize() function 
check_table_grouped <- group_by(check_table, id);

# For each id in the table, sum the number of times that its creation date/time stamp is greater than the creation date/time and less than the censor date/time of all cases in the comparison table
# EDIT: Also added timing to compare with method below
system.time(check_table_summary <- summarize(check_table_grouped, other_open_values_at_creation_count = sum((comparison_table$created < creation & comparison_table$censored > creation))));

# Result is as desired
check_table_summary;              

# EDIT: Added @David-arenburg's solution with timing
library(data.table);
setDT(check_table)[, creation2 := creation];
setkey(comparison_table, created, censored);
system.time(foverlaps_table <- foverlaps(check_table, comparison_table, by.x = c("creation", "creation2"))[, sum(!is.na(id)), by = i.id]);

# Same results as above
foverlaps_table;
```

This approach works fine for small data sets like the one in this example.  However, even though I'm using vectorized operations, the computation time grows exponentially because the operation count is: (3 * nrow comparisons) * (nrow sum(nrow) calculations).  At nrow=10,000, time is around 14s, at nrow=100,000, time is > 20 minutes.  My actual nrow is ~ 1,000,000.

Is there a more efficient way to do this calculation?  I'm currently looking into multicore options, but even those will only linearly reduce the execution time.  Your help is appreciated.  Thanks!

EDIT: Added @David-arenburg's `data.table::foverlaps` solution, which also works and is faster for nrow < 1000.  However, it is slower than the `summarize` solution for larger numbers of rows.  At 10,000 rows it was twice as long.  At 50,000 rows, I gave up waiting after 10x as long.  Interestingly, the `foverlaps` solution doesn't seem to trigger automatic garbage collection, so constantly sits at max RAM (64GB on my system) whereas the `summarize` solution periodically triggers the automatic garbage collection, so never exceeds ~ 40GB of RAM.  I'm unsure if this is related to the speed differences.

FINAL EDIT: I have re-written the question in a way that makes it much easier for respondents to generate large tables with suitable created/censored dateTimes. I've also simplified and explained the problem more clearly, making it clear that the lookup table is very large (violating `data.table::foverlaps` assumptions). I've even built in timing comparison to make it super simple to test with large cases! Details here: [Efficient method for counting open cases at time of each case's submission in large data set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34245295/efficient-method-for-counting-open-cases-at-time-of-each-cases-submission-in-la)

Thanks again for your help everyone! :)

Comment: This is a good question but FYI your use of horizontal space is a little out of control and makes your code less readable. Try to limit it to 80 - 100 characters a line.

Comment: How big is your actual `comparison_table`?

Comment: to add to Kaashaa's Q, and how big is your `check_table`?

Comment: @nrussell: I optimized it to be readable when copy-pasted on a standard monitor, but you're absolutely right that it makes it hard to read on the webpage.  I'll try to make everything more vertical in the future.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Khashaa & @Arun: I've read the `foverlaps` documentation more closely, and I think you're both on to the problem: My comparison table is very large, the same size as the check table (~1M rows).  The `foverlaps` function is optimal for small comparison tables, which is probably why it's slower for this operation than `summarize` above a certain threshold.

I'm going to come up with a better reproducible example that allows the easy increasing of the table size in order to compare times.  Given that I have already posted several edits, I'll post it as a new question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yet another `foverlaps` solution. Assuming that `comparison_table` is not too large

```
library(data.table);
setkey(comparison_table, created, censored);    
times <- sort(unique(c(comparison_table$created, comparison_table$censored)))
dt <- data.table(creation=times+1)[, creation2 := creation];
setkey(dt, creation, creation2)
x <- foverlaps(comparison_table, dt, by.x = c("created", "censored"))[,.N,creation]$N
check_table$newcol <- x[findInterval(check_table$creation, times)]
```

Comment: I'll credit this response as the answer.  It doesn't solve the efficiency problem, but I don't want @Khashaa's work to go unrewarded. :)

Comment: Was this more efficient than my solution?

Comment: @DavidArenburg - I can't get Khashaa's solution to work on the actual data set because the creation times in check & comparison tables are actually the same, which I explained very poorly in this example.  That's my bad, which is why I rewrote it to make that issue more clear.  As such, I can't readily compare the efficiency of his solution to yours.  My suspicion is that it would reduce to the same as yours in order to work on the actual data.  I feel bad that your answer wasn't also credited. If you wish to repost it, I'll flag it as answer here as well.  Thanks!