# Efficient method for counting open cases at time of each case's submission in large data set

Tags: r, performance, data.table, dplyr, vectorization

In a large data set (~1M cases), each case has a "created" and a "censored" `dateTime`. I want to count the number of other cases that were open at the time each case was created.  Cases are open between their "created" and "censored" `dataTimes`.

Several solutions work well on small datasets (<100,000 cases), but computation time grows exponentially.  My estimate is that computation time increases as a function 3n^2.  By n=100,000 cases, computation time is >20 mins on my server with 6 * 4GHz cores & 64GB RAM. Even with multi-core libraries, at best, I could reduce the time by a factor of 8 or 10.  Not enough to handle ~1M cases.

I'm looking for a more efficient method to do this calculation.  Below I have provided a function that allows you to easily create large numbers of "created" and "censored" `dateTime` pairs along with two solutions tried so far, using `dplyr` and `data.table` libraries.  The timings are reported to the user for simplicity.  You can simply change the "CASE_COUNT" variable at the top to re-execute and view times again and easily compare the timing of other solutions you might have to suggest.

I will update the original post with other solutions to give proper credit to their authors.  Thanks in advance for your help with this!

```
# Load libraries used in this example
library(dplyr);
library(data.table);
# Not on CRAN. See: http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/IRanges.html
library(IRanges);

# Set seed for reproducibility 
set.seed(123)

# Set number of cases & date range variables
CASE_COUNT  <<- 1000;
RANGE_START <- as.POSIXct("2000-01-01 00:00:00", 
                          format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", 
                          tz="UTC", origin="1970-01-01");
RANGE_END   <- as.POSIXct("2012-01-01 00:00:00", 
                          format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", 
                          tz="UTC", origin="1970-01-01");

# Select which solutions you want to run in this test           
RUN_SOLUTION_1 <- TRUE;     # dplyr::summarize() + comparisons
RUN_SOLUTION_2 <- TRUE;     # data.table:foverlaps()
RUN_SOLUTION_3 <- TRUE;     # data.table aggregation + comparisons
RUN_SOLUTION_4 <- TRUE;     # IRanges::IRanges + countOverlaps()
RUN_SOLUTION_5 <- TRUE;     # data.table::frank()

# Function to generate random creation & censor dateTime pairs
# The censor time always has to be after the creation time
# Credit to @DirkEddelbuettel for this smart function
# (https://stackoverflow.com/users/143305/dirk-eddelbuettel)

generate_cases_table <- function(n = CASE_COUNT, start_val=RANGE_START, end_val=RANGE_END) {
    # Measure duration between start_val & end_val
    duration <- as.numeric(difftime(end_val, start_val, unit="secs"));

    # Select random values in duration to create start_offset
    start_offset   <- runif(n, 0, duration);

    # Calculate the creation time list
    created_list  <- start_offset + start_val;

    # Calculate acceptable time range for censored values
    # since they must always be after their respective creation value
    censored_range <- as.numeric(difftime(RANGE_END, created_list, unit="secs"));

    # Select random values in duration to create end_offset
    creation_to_censored_times <- runif(n, 0, censored_range);

    censored_list <- created_list + creation_to_censored_times;

    # Create and return a data.table with creation & censor values
    # calculated from start or end with random offsets
    return_table  <- data.table(id       = 1:n,
                                created  = created_list,
                                censored = censored_list);

    return(return_table);
}

# Create the data table with the desired number of cases specified by CASE_COUNT above
cases_table <- generate_cases_table();

solution_1_function <- function (cases_table) { 
    # SOLUTION 1: Using dplyr::summarize:

    # Group by id to set parameters for summarize() function 
    cases_table_grouped <- group_by(cases_table, id);

    # Count the instances where other cases were created before
    # and censored after each case using vectorized sum() within summarize()

    cases_table_summary <- summarize(cases_table_grouped, 
                           open_cases_at_creation = sum((cases_table$created  < created & 
                                                         cases_table$censored > created)));
    solution_1_table <<- as.data.table(cases_table_summary, key="id");        
} # End solution_1_function

solution_2_function <- function (cases_table) {
    # SOLUTION 2: Using data.table::foverlaps:

    # Adapted from solution provided by @Davidarenburg
    # (https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001626/david-arenburg)

    # The foverlaps() solution tends to crash R with large case counts
    # I suspect it has to do with memory assignment of the very large objects
    # It maxes RAM on my system (64GB) before crashing, possibly attempting
    # to write beyond its assigned memory limits.
    # I'll submit a reproduceable bug to the data.table team since
    # foverlaps() is pretty new and known to be occasionally unstable

    if (CASE_COUNT > 50000) {
        stop("The foverlaps() solution tends to crash R with large case counts. Not running.");
    }

    setDT(cases_table)[, created_dupe := created];
    setkey(cases_table, created, censored);

    foverlaps_table  <- foverlaps(cases_table[,c("id","created","created_dupe"), with=FALSE],
                                  cases_table[,c("id","created","censored"),    with=FALSE], 
                                  by.x=c("created","created_dupe"))[order(i.id),.N-1,by=i.id];

    foverlaps_table  <- dplyr::rename(foverlaps_table, id=i.id, open_cases_at_creation=V1);

    solution_2_table <<- as.data.table(foverlaps_table, key="id");
} # End solution_2_function

solution_3_function <- function (cases_table) {    
    # SOLUTION 3: Using data.table aggregation instead of dplyr::summarize

    # Idea suggested by @jangorecki
    # (https://stackoverflow.com/users/2490497/jangorecki)

    # Count the instances where other cases were created before
    # and censored after each case using vectorized sum() with data.table aggregation

    cases_table_aggregated <- cases_table[order(id), sum((cases_table$created  < created & 
                                                     cases_table$censored > created)),by=id];   

    solution_3_table <<- as.data.table(dplyr::rename(cases_table_aggregated, open_cases_at_creation=V1), key="id");

} # End solution_3_function

solution_4_function <- function (cases_table) { 
    # SOLUTION 4: Using IRanges package

    # Adapted from solution suggested by @alexis_laz
    # (https://stackoverflow.com/users/2414948/alexis-laz)

    # The IRanges package generates ranges efficiently, intended for genome sequencing
    # but working perfectly well on this data, since POSIXct values are numeric-representable
    solution_4_table <<- data.table(id      = cases_table$id,
                     open_cases_at_creation = countOverlaps(IRanges(cases_table$created, 
                                                                    cases_table$created), 
                                                            IRanges(cases_table$created, 
                                                                    cases_table$censored))-1, key="id");

} # End solution_4_function

solution_5_function <- function (cases_table) {
    # SOLUTION 5: Using data.table::frank()

    # Adapted from solution suggested by @danas.zuokas
    # (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1249481/danas-zuokas)

    n <- CASE_COUNT;

    # For every case compute the number of other cases
    # with `created` less than `created` of other cases
    r1 <- data.table::frank(c(cases_table[, created], cases_table[, created]), ties.method = 'first')[1:n];

    # For every case compute the number of other cases
    # with `censored` less than `created`
    r2 <- data.table::frank(c(cases_table[, created], cases_table[, censored]), ties.method = 'first')[1:n];

    solution_5_table <<- data.table(id      = cases_table$id,
                     open_cases_at_creation = r1 - r2, key="id");

} # End solution_5_function;

# Execute user specified functions;
if (RUN_SOLUTION_1)
    solution_1_timing <- system.time(solution_1_function(cases_table)); 
if (RUN_SOLUTION_2) {
    solution_2_timing <- try(system.time(solution_2_function(cases_table)));
    cases_table <- select(cases_table, -created_dupe);
}
if (RUN_SOLUTION_3)
    solution_3_timing <- system.time(solution_3_function(cases_table)); 
if (RUN_SOLUTION_4)
    solution_4_timing <- system.time(solution_4_function(cases_table));
if (RUN_SOLUTION_5)
    solution_5_timing <- system.time(solution_5_function(cases_table));         

# Check generated tables for comparison
if (RUN_SOLUTION_1 && RUN_SOLUTION_2 && class(solution_2_timing)!="try-error") {
    same_check1_2 <- all(solution_1_table$open_cases_at_creation == solution_2_table$open_cases_at_creation);
} else {same_check1_2 <- TRUE;}
if (RUN_SOLUTION_1 && RUN_SOLUTION_3) {
    same_check1_3 <- all(solution_1_table$open_cases_at_creation == solution_3_table$open_cases_at_creation);
} else {same_check1_3 <- TRUE;}
if (RUN_SOLUTION_1 && RUN_SOLUTION_4) {
    same_check1_4 <- all(solution_1_table$open_cases_at_creation == solution_4_table$open_cases_at_creation);
} else {same_check1_4 <- TRUE;}
if (RUN_SOLUTION_1 && RUN_SOLUTION_5) {
    same_check1_5 <- all(solution_1_table$open_cases_at_creation == solution_5_table$open_cases_at_creation);
} else {same_check1_5 <- TRUE;}
if (RUN_SOLUTION_2 && RUN_SOLUTION_3 && class(solution_2_timing)!="try-error") {
    same_check2_3 <- all(solution_2_table$open_cases_at_creation == solution_3_table$open_cases_at_creation);
} else {same_check2_3 <- TRUE;}
if (RUN_SOLUTION_2 && RUN_SOLUTION_4 && class(solution_2_timing)!="try-error") {
    same_check2_4 <- all(solution_2_table$open_cases_at_creation == solution_4_table$open_cases_at_creation);
} else {same_check2_4 <- TRUE;}
if (RUN_SOLUTION_2 && RUN_SOLUTION_5 && class(solution_2_timing)!="try-error") {
    same_check2_5 <- all(solution_2_table$open_cases_at_creation == solution_5_table$open_cases_at_creation);
} else {same_check2_5 <- TRUE;}
if (RUN_SOLUTION_3 && RUN_SOLUTION_4) {
    same_check3_4 <- all(solution_3_table$open_cases_at_creation == solution_4_table$open_cases_at_creation);
} else {same_check3_4 <- TRUE;}
if (RUN_SOLUTION_3 && RUN_SOLUTION_5) {
    same_check3_5 <- all(solution_3_table$open_cases_at_creation == solution_5_table$open_cases_at_creation);
} else {same_check3_5 <- TRUE;}
if (RUN_SOLUTION_4 && RUN_SOLUTION_5) {
    same_check4_5 <- all(solution_4_table$open_cases_at_creation == solution_5_table$open_cases_at_creation);
} else {same_check4_5 <- TRUE;}


same_check    <- all(same_check1_2, same_check1_3, same_check1_4, same_check1_5,
                     same_check2_3, same_check2_4, same_check2_5, same_check3_4,
                     same_check3_5, same_check4_5);

# Report summary of results to user
cat("This execution was for", CASE_COUNT, "cases.\n",
    "It is", same_check, "that all solutions match.\n");
if (RUN_SOLUTION_1)
    cat("The dplyr::summarize() solution took", solution_1_timing[3], "seconds.\n");
if (RUN_SOLUTION_2 && class(solution_2_timing)!="try-error")
    cat("The data.table::foverlaps() solution took", solution_2_timing[3], "seconds.\n");
if (RUN_SOLUTION_3)
    cat("The data.table aggregation solution took", solution_3_timing[3], "seconds.\n");
if (RUN_SOLUTION_4)
    cat("The IRanges solution solution took", solution_4_timing[3], "seconds.\n");
if (RUN_SOLUTION_5)
    cat("The data.table:frank() solution solution took", solution_5_timing[3], "seconds.\n\n");
```

The `data.table::foverlaps()` solution is faster for fewer cases (<5000 or so; depends on randomness in addition to n since it uses binary search to optimize). The `dplyr::summarize()` solution is faster for more cases (>5,000 or so).  Much beyond 100,000, neither solution is viable as they're both too slow.

EDIT: Added a third solution based on the idea suggested by @jangorecki that uses `data.table` aggregation instead of `dplyr::summarize()`, and is otherwise similar to the `dplyr` solution.  For up to around 50,000 cases, it is the fastest solution. Beyond 50,000 cases, the `dplyr::summarize()` solution is slightly faster, but not by much.  Sadly, for 1M cases it's still not practical.

EDIT2: Added a fourth solution adapted from the solution suggested by @alexis_laz that uses the `IRanges` package and its `countOverlaps` function.
It is significantly faster than the 3 other solutions.  With 50,000 cases it was almost 400% faster than solutions 1 & 3.

EDIT3: Modified case generating function to properly exercise the "censored" condition.  Thanks to @jangorecki for catching the limitation of the previous version.

EDIT4: Rewrote to allow user to select which solutions to execute and to use `system.time()` for timing comparison with garbage collection before each execution for more accurate timing (as per @jangorecki's astute observation) - Also added some condition checks for crash cases.

EDIT5: Added a fifth solution adapted from the solution suggested by @danas.zuokas using `rank()`.  My experimentation suggests that it's always at least an order of magnitude slower than the other solutions.  At 10,000 cases, it takes 44 seconds vs. 3.5 seconds for `dplyr::summarize` and 0.36 seconds for `IRanges` solutions.

FINAL EDIT: I've made slight modifications to solution 5 that was suggested by @danas.zuokas, and matching the observation by @Khashaa about types.  I've set the type `as.numeric` in the `dataTime` generation function which drastically speeds up `rank` as it operates on `integers` or `doubles` instead of `dateTime` objects(increases speed of other functions too, but not as drastically).  With some testing, setting `ties.method='first'` yields results consistent with the intent.  `data.table::frank` is faster than both `base::rank` and `IRanges::rank`.  `bit64::rank` is fastest, but it seems to handle ties differently than `data.table::frank` and I can't get it to handle them as desired.  Once `bit64` is loaded, it masks a large number of types and functions, changing the results of `data.table::frank` along the way.  The specific reasons why are beyond the scope of this question.

POST END NOTE: Turns out that `data.table::frank` handles `POSIXct` `dateTimes` efficiently, whereas neither `base::rank` nor `IRanges::rank` seem to.  As such, even the `as.numeric` (or `as.integer`) type setting isn't necessary with `data.table::frank` and there is no loss of precision from the conversion, so there are fewer `ties.method` discrepancies.
Thank you to everyone who contributed!  I learned a lot!  Much appreciated! :)
Credit will be included in my source-code.

ENDNOTE: This question is a refined and clarified version, with easier to use and more readable example code, of [More efficient method for counting open cases as of creation time of each case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34213315/) - I've separated it here to not overwhelm the original post with too many edits and to simplify the creation of large numbers of `dataTime` pairs in the example code.  That way, you don't have to work as hard to answer.  Thanks again!

Comment: @RichardScrivens - Khashaa's solution works, so I gave him an upvote.  But it doesn't solve the efficiency problem, so it doesn't really answer the question.  That being said, I do want to recognize his work, so I have now also credited him with the answer for the original question.  I hope that's appropriate?

Comment: Split the dataset up into smaller chunks?

Comment: did you try data.table aggregation? it should do the same what `dplyr::summarize`, for large number of groups  you should get bigger speedup.

Comment: BTW. use `system.time` instead of `Sys.time` if you want to compare timings.

Comment: Efficiency? Performance? Why not use a Relational Database? An SQL engine can aggregate millions upon millions of records including conditional `Count()`. And R maintains libraries for all the major RDMS's: Oracle, SQL Server, DB2, PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQLite. MS Access.

Comment: @Parfait SQL is slower, often much slower than in-memory in R with data.table or dplyr - see extensive benchmark here: https://github.com/szilard/benchm-databases

Comment: Perhaps, if your dates are integer-representable, you could try "IRanges" package; `countOverlaps(IRanges(as.numeric(cases_table$created), as.numeric(cases_table$created)), IRanges(as.numeric(cases_table$created), as.numeric(cases_table$censored))) - 1`

Comment: @NBATrends: I can't think of a way to split the data that still allows it to count open cases across the split data chunks.  Do you have any ideas how that could be done?

Comment: @jangorecki: Thanks for your suggestion about `system.time`.  Could you explain why it's more appropriate here?  My understanding is that `system.time` is used for single calls, making it harder to use on a block of code, where I have seen the `Sys.time` start/stop + `difftime` approach used for timing.  Are you suggesting wrapping the code in functions to execute it as a single command?  Does the user/system timing breakdown in `system.time` provide useful information that makes this extra step worth it?

Comment: @jangorecki: I've added a third solution that uses your idea to substitute `data.table` aggregation for `dplyr::summarize` and added it to the comparison timings.  It's definitely fastest for up to around 50,000 cases.  After that, the `dplyr::summarize` version is slightly faster, but not by much.  Unfortunately, it's still not practical for 1M cases in my dataset.  Thanks for the idea! It forced me to learn more `data.table` which is always useful! :)

Comment: @alexis_laz: I have added a fourth solution based on your suggestion using the `IRanges` package.  Wow!  It is significantly faster than the other solutions, especially with larger data sets.  I'm going to test it some more and see what else I can optimize with it as it's still slower than I'd like for 1M cases, but it's definitely the right direction..  Please post your solution as an  answer so that I can at least give you an upvote for the significant efficiency increase! :)

Comment: The `BiocParalell` vignette here seems to suggest that it's possible to use `snow` to cluster the `IRanges::countOverlaps` calculation, which is the slow one, but the specifics are a bit beyond me (I'm on Windows): https://bioc.ism.ac.jp/packages/3.0/bioc/vignettes/BiocParallel/inst/doc/IntroductionToBiocParallel.pdf

Comment: @MekkiMacAulay : I guess that using the "numeric" instead of the "Date" class will be more efficient for all solutions because of method dispatching on operators. BTW, in your 1st solution you scan a "CASE_COUNT" vector 4 times (once for each of ">", "<", "&", "sum"). I believe that minimizing comparisons with something like `sum(cases_table$censored[created > cases_table$created] > created)` should gain a 2-3x speed gain (with a worst case of 0x gain).

Comment: @MekkiMacAulay ready about `gcFirst` argument in `?system.time`.

Comment: For this problem, it might be well suited to give a try in C code; even naive implementations should be faster than any of the other approaches (including parallel computations). (BTW, feel free to build a compact anwer to have all info gathered in one place; with all the effort you've put in this Q it'll feel a bit awkard if I post a 2 lines answer.. :-))

Comment: In each case (i= 1, ..., n), you need to compare to each of the other cases, giving you polynomial time complexity (O(n^2)). To get around this, you need to reduce the number of comparisons. Any other approach will be suboptimal.... 

I suggest something based on a binary search approach on the sorted `cases_table$censored` vector. But, I have to ask, is this streaming data? IE- how frequently are you planning to run this? Twenty minutes isn't that long for something that isn't being run very frequently. Is it worth the development time?

Comment: @Alex: Yes, that was exactly what I figured too.  Bear in mind that the 20 minutes measure is for 100,000 cases.  My real data is ~1M cases and I have 3-4 such calculations.  The solution provided by alexis_laz allows the execution in about 5 hours each (vs 8+ days each, which was my estimate for the original solution), which might be ok since, as you correctly point out, I don't need to run this repeatedly.

Comment: @jangorecki: Ah, yes.  Good point.  I didn't think about garbage collection.  I suppose manual gc() calls would be silly.  I'll modify the code to make the solutions individual functions, timed with system.time.  That will also allow the user to enable individual functions to compare more easily at the top of the code, also addressing your concerns about the example being to big. :)

Comment: If you can run it in parallel then it's still a total of 5 hours given that you have 6 cores. Seems reasonable to me... I often build models that that days to run, such as SVM.

Comment: @Alex Yeah, I might settle for that at this point.

Comment: If you used a 5 hour solution yesterday (when alexis_laz gave you that answer), you'd be done now vs spinning your wheels on it more.

Comment: @Alex Thanks for your concern.  This is also a learning exercise for me, so I feel the time is well spent.  Further, I want to respect the other people who have provided solutions by incorporating them as there has been interest in the timing comparisons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The answer is updated with the regards to a comment by the author of the question.**

I would suggest a solution using ranks. Tables are created as in [a follow up to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34213315/more-efficient-method-for-counting-open-cases-as-of-creation-time-of-each-case), or using the `dateTime` pairs generation function in the present question. Both should work.

```
n <- cases_table[, .N]

# For every case compute the number of other cases
# with `created` less than `creation` of other cases
r1 <- data.table::frank(c(cases_table[, created], cases_table[, created]),
           ties.method = 'first')[1:n]

# For every case compute the number of other cases
# with `censored` less than `created`
r2 <- data.table::frank(c(cases_table[, created], cases_table[, censored]),
           ties.method = 'first')[1:n]
```

Taking difference `r1 - r2` (-1 not required with ties.method='first') gives the result (eliminating ranks of `created`). In terms of efficiency it takes only finding ranks of a vector of length of that number of rows in `cases_table`.  `data.table::frank` handles `POSIXct` `dateTime` objects as quickly as `numeric` objects (unlike `base::rank`), so no type conversion is required.

Comment: where are `check_table` and `comparison_table` defined/created?

Comment: I would advise to copy the code required to reproduce those object as your answer cannot be reproduced in scope on this question.

Comment: I rewrote the question here to clarify that there really isn't a separate check & comparison table.  I want to avoid blurring that distinction as it was misleading previously.  In your solution, could you not simply generate the `cases_table` using the function I wrote in this version of the question and simply pass its different columns to `rank` as you have done? Would it not have the same effect?

Comment: Thanks for your suggested solution @danas.zuokas.  I have added it to the main code as solution 5.  My testing suggests that it's significantly slower than the other approaches (you can simply copy-paste the whole code to run it yourself and see the timing comparisons).  I appreciate your effort!  I've learned more about `rank` along the way! :)

Comment: @Mekki MacAulay This is due to the class of variable. If you convert it to integer (number of seconds from 1970) then it runs very fast even for big `n`. I will update the answer so you can see it.

Comment: @MekkiMacAulay, this should be the fastest solution.  Don't forget `as.integer` part, because it is the essence of the solution. It gets even faster with `data.table::frankv`.

Comment: @Khashaa: Indeed.  I have been testing and I came to the same conclusion: `data.table::frank` is the fastest solution.  I also noticed that I have to use `as.numeric`, not `as.integer` or a small amount of precision is  lost that slightly throws off larger cases.  Nevertheless, this solution appears to be the best by far.  I will update main post.

Comment: With some more testing, I'm satisfied with the final results.  It can handle ~1M cases in seconds.  data.table::frank() is faster, and ties.method='first' is more consistent with the desired comparisons, though count is only ever off by one and only in a few cases, which isn't a problem. As this solution is by far the fastest, I'm going to credit it as answer.  Thanks very much! :)

Comment: Turns out that `data.table::frank` handles `POSIXct` `dateTimes` efficiently, whereas neither `base::rank` nor `IRanges::rank` seem to.  As such, even the `as.numeric` (or `as.integer`) isn't necessary with `data.table::frank` and there is no loss of precision from the conversion, so there are no `ties.method` discrepancies.

Comment: Dint read the Q/A fully, but looking at the answer, it seems like `frankv` (SE version) would be much better here.

Answer (score 3):

This will probably not answer precisely your question well as the reproducible example is not exposed to `cases_table$censored > created` condition, see `min` and `max` below. Making smaller example would help you to spot such issues. Also you should use `set.seed` in your example.

```
set.seed(123)
library(data.table)
CASE_COUNT  <- 1000;
RANGE_START <- as.POSIXct("2000-01-01 00:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC", origin="1970-01-01");
RANGE_END   <- as.POSIXct("2012-01-01 00:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC", origin="1970-01-01");
generate_cases_table <- function(n = CASE_COUNT, start=RANGE_START, end=RANGE_END) {
    half_duration <- as.numeric(difftime(end, start, unit="sec")) / 2;
    start_offset  <- runif(n, 0, half_duration);
    end_offset    <- runif(n, 0, half_duration);
    data.table(id       = 1:n,created  = start + start_offset,censored = end   - end_offset)
}
cases_table = generate_cases_table()

cases_table[, .(min_censored = min(censored), max_created = max(created))]
#          min_censored         max_created
#1: 2006-01-01 13:02:12 2005-12-30 04:40:49

setorder(cases_table, created)[, created_so_far := .I - 1L]
cases_table[, censored_after := cases_table[cases_table, on = c("created" = "censored"), roll = Inf, which = TRUE]]
```

The `roll` join may need to be altered but I was not able to test due to mentioned issue with example data.
The `which` argument is just extracting the row number from rolling join, for sorted data it also means a *count of observations after the join occurs*. Mentioned issue results that value to be always 1000 cause all `created` are smaller than `censored`.
For detailed description of data.table rolling joins see this post: http://gormanalysis.com/r-data-table-rolling-joins/
Once you manage to apply that solution please share your timing difference in comments.

Comment: Thanks for your suggested solution.  I knew that the created & censored times didn't overlap when I wrote the generating function, but I figured that since such cases were valid, it would be ok.  I see what you're getting at with it not properly exercising the second condition.  I'll try to find a way to adapt the generating function and will post it.

I had been trying to think of a rolling-join type solution, so I definitely think you're on to something.  Awesome!

Comment: Case generation function has been rewritten to address the issue you pointed out.  Thanks!  Will try your solution now.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I've read the blog post you provided, along with data.table docs, and have failed to get it to work.  The  `censored_after` column generates correctly, providing an upper limit for the the roll along with the `created_so_far` providing the lower limit.  However, I can't figure out how to do the comparison to create the rolling count itself.  I'm just not talented enough with data.table.  I appreciate your effort.